# Required dynamic Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect

Tags: php, zend-form

I've got a `<select multiple>` populated on start up with some values, but where additional options are added via Javascript. However I'd like now to validate this element, that at least one of the options within has been selected.

I'm using Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect to perform the validation:

```
$tags = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('cms_tags');
$tags->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false)->setRequired(true);
```

However, of course, this is not working. How can I do something as simple as checking for not emptiness of the `cms_tags` array without resorting to overloading `isValid` function?

PS. Validate_Not_Empty is not working as well.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['cms_tags']) && is_array($_POST['cms_tags']) && sizeof($_POST['cms_tags']) > 0)`

Comment: I know how to do it in pure PHP - the problem is to setup validator that will do it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, the solution to my question is my code. Unfortunately, Zend, at least to me, has a bug - the problem with my data was an empty value that appeared at the end of the values array, so `cms_tags[]=5`, `cms_tags[]=` was considered invalid for this kind of validator. If this a valid behavior, or not, I'll leave it to Zend folks, but this at least answers my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public function isValid($data) {

    $etat_valid = parent::isValid($data);
    if(isset($data['cms_tags'])){
        // Add your validators
        // for example:
        if("" == $data['cms_tags']){
           $this->getElement('cms_tags')->addErrors(array('This value is required and can not be empty'));
           $etat_valid = false;
        }
    }
    return $etat_valid;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but: a) `without resorting to overloading isValid function`, and b) already resolved this issue

Comment: @eithedog : Yes, I saw, but as I typed my answer during your validation and as I don't think off topic, I gave this answer for those who are interested.
But if you do not like it, I can remove it. :)